# Uncaught SyntaxError on <!Doctype

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I created an empty project with Node and I bought a complete template online.
I'm pointing the init of page on my index.html but the console give me back this error (As the console show in the image)
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNCVY.png)

By deleting the `<!DOCTYPE HTML` the error turns on the < HTML.
It seems like the server doesn't recognize it is an HTML file.

Here another screenshot to show root, index file, and the server JavaScript

[root,index,server.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQclu.png)

Comment: You're trying to run `JSON.parse()` on a string that isn't JSON. The error is, admittedly, not very intuitive.

Comment: app.use(bodyParser.json());
Do you mean this. Actually I really don't know much about this line. Cause i was following up a tutorial to setup a backend with node. And i'm blocked just at the beginning, damn me! Anyway delete this code doesn't resolve anything. I continue the tutorial, maybe i'll find something

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are referencing stylesheets and other resources in your HTML, but in your server-side code you've set up a "catch-all" GET route that always responds with an HTML document. When the browser requests these resources, that "catch-all" route is matched and so it sends back HTML (instead of the actual requested resource).

One solution to this is to simply include the [`express.static()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) middleware *before* your route handlers so that your page assets get transferred correctly.